# Node.js: Is there a synchronous version of the `http.get` method in node.js?

Tags: http, node.js, asynchronous, get, synchronous

Is there a synchronous version of the `http.get` method in node.js?

Something like:

```
http.getSync({
    host: 'google.com', 
    port: 80, 
    path: '/'
}, function(response){  

});

console.log(response)
```

Sometimes it would be very useful.

Comment: Synchronous I/O is sometimes useful but it's not the intent of the event-driven runtime that is node.js -- she's built for speed, not comfort! =)

Answer (score -14, accepted):

No, there isn't. I honestly don't see the use case.

If you expand upon your use case or a problem that you're trying to solve, I'll try to answer that.

Comment: How about this for a use case:  Making an http request during server initialization to pull in config data before starting an application.  Sure, you can add logic to deal with this asynchronously but it's easier to implement in a synchronous fashion.

Comment: Have 5000 rows, need call an http request for each row :-/, id=0;var x=function(){ http.get('http://foo', function(){ id++; if(id<rows.length) x(); }); } x(); ..... or x.forEach(function(){ http.get('http://foo', function(){ end! }); }); .... is very clean call an forEach and less code. It is impossible that all software created are asyncs, is a totally ignorant. Were developed in over 14 different languages ​​and I can say that there are always times when you need a function to be synchronized.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: @vikramaditya234 in 2012 (5 years ago) it answered the question; not sure about today.

Comment: @jprichardson agree, regret overlooking. can u change something in answer so I can unmark it. System doesnt allow me to remove downvote otherwise

Comment: "I don't see the use case" !== "There is no use case".

Comment: This was answered over 9 years ago. If I could delete the answer I would. Much has changed since then.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [sync-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request) library that is pretty easily to use. Internally it spawns a child process synchronously and uses [then-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/then-request), so options are similar to that library.

As others have stated, I would caution against using this in your runtime logic. However, it can be very handy for loading configuration.

If you are loading configuration, another strategy can be using a separate script to start your process. Example:

```
var http = require("http"),
    cp   = require("child_process");

// Starting process
if (process.argv.length < 3) {
    return http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
        var config = {
            statusCode : res.statusCode,
            headers    : res.headers
        };

        cp.fork(module.filename, [JSON.stringify(config)]);
    });
}

// Config provided
var config = JSON.parse(process.argv[2]);

console.log(config.statusCode);
```